# replace a value in one column with a value from a second column on condition of a value from a third column from different rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Object  = c("Klaus","Klaus","Peter","Peter","Daniel","Daniel"),
                 PointA  = as.numeric(c("7",NA,"17",NA,NA,NA)),
                 PointB  = as.numeric(c("18","22",NA,NA,"17",NA)),
                 measure = c("1","2","1","2","1","2")
                 )
```

And I want this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Object  = c("Klaus","Klaus","Peter","Peter","Daniel","Daniel"),
                  PointA  = as.numeric(c("7","18","17",NA,NA,"17")),
                  PointB  = as.numeric(c("18","22",NA,NA,"17",NA)),
                  measure = c("1","2","1","2","1","2")
                  )
```

Which is, if there is a no value for an Object for PointA for measure == 2, I want it replaced with PointB from measure == 1 of the same Object.

First thing that comes to mind is:

```
library(dplyr)
df$PointA <- coalesce(df$PointA, df$PointB)
```

But afaik there is no way to make this condional.

Then I thought maybe something like:

```
df$PointA[is.na(df$PointA)] <- df$PointB
```

But this does not differentiate for the measure.

So I thought about:

```
df$PointA <- ifelse(df$measure == 2 & is.na(df$PointA), df$PointB, df$PointA)
```

But that does not take into account that I need the corresponding value from measure == 1.

Now, I am at a loss here. I am out of ideas how to approch this. Help?

Edit: I got two very good solutions already, but both rely on the order in the data frame. I tried, but obviously my example was to simple. I am looking for something that works under the following condition, too:

```
df1 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)), ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option is using `row_number()` from `dplyr`. In case you need to sort your dataframe first, you can insert an `arrange` statement.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(Object, measure) %>% 
  group_by(Object) %>% 
  mutate(PointA = if_else(measure == 2 & is.na(PointA), PointB[row_number()-1], PointA))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Object [3]
#   Object PointA PointB measure
#   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
# 1 Daniel     NA     17 1      
# 2 Daniel     17     NA 2      
# 3 Klaus       7     18 1      
# 4 Klaus      18     22 2      
# 5 Peter      17     NA 1      
# 6 Peter      NA     NA 2
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but it relies on the order in the example df1. What if: df1 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)), ]

Comment: @Markus I've edited my answer, now it satisfies the additional case

Answer (score 1):

You could use `coalesce` +`lag` as shown below:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df1 %>%
   arrange(Object, measure) %>%
   group_by(Object) %>%
   mutate(PointA = coalesce(PointA, lag(PointB)))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Object [3]
  Object PointA PointB measure
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
1 Klaus       7     18 1      
2 Klaus      18     18 2      
3 Peter      17     NA 1      
4 Peter      NA     NA 2      
5 Daniel     NA     17 1      
6 Daniel     17     NA 2
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, but it relies on the order in the example df1. What if: df1 <- df1[sample(nrow(df1)), ]

Answer (score 1):

This could be condensed, but it should be relatively clear and doesn't rely on the row order at all. Beware if you have multiple rows for the same Object/Measure pair - the self-join will have multiple matches and you'll end up with a lot more rows than you started with.

```
library(dplyr)

df_fill = df1 %>%
  filter(measure == 1) %>%
  select(Object, fill_in = PointB) %>%
  mutate(needs_fill = 1L)


result = df1 %>%
  mutate(needs_fill = if_else(measure == 2 & is.na(PointA), 1L, NA_integer_)) %>%
  left_join(df_fill) %>%
  mutate(PointA = coalesce(PointA, fill_in)) %>%
  select(-fill_in, -needs_fill)

result
#   Object PointA PointB measure
# 1  Klaus      7     18       1
# 2  Klaus     18     22       2
# 3  Peter     17     NA       1
# 4  Peter     NA     NA       2
# 5 Daniel     NA     17       1
# 6 Daniel     17     NA       2
```

Same as above but without saving the intermediate object:

```
result = df1 %>%
  mutate(needs_fill = if_else(measure == 2 & is.na(PointA), 1L, NA_integer_)) %>%
  left_join(
    df1 %>%
      filter(measure == 1) %>%
      select(Object, fill_in = PointB) %>%
      mutate(needs_fill = 1L)
  ) %>%
  mutate(PointA = coalesce(PointA, fill_in)) %>%
  select(-fill_in, -needs_fill)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work as intended. Testing it, I get 17 for result$PointA[result$Object == "Daniel" & result$measure == 1] which should be NA. Looking at your code I do not understand how you could possible got your result table.

Comment: @Markus Fixed it so it matches your output. As to the confusion, have you tried running it one line at a time? If there's any particular part that's confusing, I'd be happy to explain it. Basically I filter down to the values you PointB values that you want to be replacements, and I join those back to the original data and then fill in the blanks. On a very large table sorting is expensive, this method should be more efficient.